# libX11.so: undefined reference to `xcb_wait_for_reply64'

Tags: php, apache

Estoy instalando *PHP* y me aparece este error que no sé como resolverlo:

> -lmysqlclient -lgd -lfreetype -lX11 -lXpm -lpng -lz -ljpeg -lz -lm -ldl -lnsl -lxml2 -lz -lm -lxml2 -lz -lm -lclntsh -lxml2 -lz -lm -lxml2 -lz -lm -lcrypt -lxml2 -lz -lm -lxml2 -lz -lm -lxml2 -lz -lm -lcrypt  -o sapi/cli/php /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../lib64/libX11.so:
>
> undefined reference to `xcb_poll_for_reply64'
>
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../lib64/libX11.so:
>
> undefined reference to `xcb_wait_for_reply64' collect2: ld returned 1
>
> exit status make: *** [sapi/cli/php] Error 1

Comment: Que distribución exacta utilizas? Redhat/CentOS, que versión.

Comment: Tienes instalado el paquete libxcb? Igual también te hace falta el paquete libxcb-devel.